# Full text search engine with snapshots

Tags: pdf, lucene, full-text-search, snapshot, pdfbox

Is it possible to get a snap shot of a page of a PDF document using PDF Box? I'd like to match a page from a pdf file using a key word, then show a snapshot of the page where that text was found. Can any one point me in the right direction as to where I should begin? I plan to use Lucene and PDF box for this, with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using pdfbox.  Something like this:

```
pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
// this gets you page 1
byte[] bytes = getImageBytes(pdf, 1);
// write out bytes as an image file
```

and you can extract text using PDFTextStripper.getText()

etc.  However I think you will get better results from xpdf - it is more mature and supports many more pdf varieties.